# withdraw MAC address assignment

Tags: mac, ethernet, arp

Is it possible to un-claim ownership of a MAC address via special kinds of gratuitous ARP or possibly by sending ARP packets with special addresses (e.g. 00:00:00:00:00:00) to invalidate cache table entries on remote parties?

Comment: no answer?, Any clarification questions are also welcome!!

Comment: also my searches direct me to netscantools and nmap-nping which seem promissing...., any shortcut/experience sharing are also welcome on those tools